# Javascript .map and doing some Math on array

Tags: javascript, arrays

First post. Thanks all for helping!

```
const boo = [20, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2];

const booMap = boo.map(bebop => Math.pow(bebop,4) * 10 / 2);

booMap.push(8);
booMap.shift();

console.log(boo)
console.log(booMap)
```

Console returns:

[20, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2]

[1280, 405, 80, 1280, 80, 8]

What I am trying to do is
x^4 * 10 / 2
where x is each number in array.

What am i doing wrong? by my calculations the first number in array should be 800000.

Thanks!

Comment: why pushing and shifting?

Comment: it was 800000 until you shifted it.

Comment: What are trying to achive by .push(8); and shift(); instructions? Your code is working find but last section affects the result, that is why you dont't see 80000 as 1st element

Comment: > [20, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2].map(bebop => Math.pow(bebop,4) * 10 / 2);
// [ 800000, 1280, 405, 80, 1280, 80 ]

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I forgot this code from my previous lesson.

```
booMap.push(8);
booMap.shift();
```